# How to capture ID captured by the jQuery code and pass it on the same php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 3 dynamic dropdown list using jQuery, and PHP. My problem is that the jQuery captured the data from the 1st and passed the data on another php file to load the 2nd dropdown list that is dynamically connected to the 1st dropdown list. I want to capture the data from the 2nd dropdown list and use it on the same php file.
Here is my code for the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#college').on('change',function(){
                var collegeID = $(this).val();
                if(collegeID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'ajaxData.php',
                        data:'college_id='+collegeID,
                        success:function(html){
                            $('#course').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 
                }else{
                    $('#course').html('<option value="">Select College first</option>');
                }
            });

            $('#course').on('change',function(){
                var courseID = $(this).val();
                if(courseID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'ajaxData.php',
                        data:'course_id='+courseID,
                        success:function(html){
                            $('#year').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 
                }else{
                    $('#year').html('<option value="">Select Course first</option>'); 
                }
            });
        });
```

and here is the ajaxData.php that the jQuery passed the value taken from the 1st dropdown:

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["college_id"]) && !empty($_POST["college_id"])){
    //Get all course data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE college_id = ".$_POST['college_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY course_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Course</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['course_id'].'">'.$row['course_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Courses not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["course_id"]) && !empty($_POST["course_id"])){
    //Get all city data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM level WHERE year_id > 0");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display level list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Year Level</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['year_id'].'">'.$row['year_lvl'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Year Level not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

now I want to know the value being passed on the ajaxData.php to use it for the php file where the jQuery code resides. Thanks!

Comment: On a side note. You must never trust the content the user has posted! By using `$_POST['college_id']` straight into your sql query you make your system vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for bringing that up. Had not made the sanitize function yet!